# Delete A Branch With Tags In It

Tags: git

I have 2 questions abour deleting branch, tagging, and git's gc.

Lets say I have a project where I am maintaining 2 different version of the software.  Lets say I have created a number of tags in one of the versions.  Now lets say I know longer need to have a development line for this version as it is no longer support but I still want to keep it around for historical purposes.  So I create a tag at the HEAD of this branch and then delete the branch.

Now the first question, is it safe to assume the git's gc will not delete these commits since I still have tags that reference/have to commit is it tree?

Now let say 2 year down the road, I no longer need to need to even access that code so I delete the tags.

My second question, now that the I no longer have any tags/branch that reference/have in their history those commits, will git's gc completely delete those commit (at whatever interval it is set to)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now the first question, is it safe to assume the git's gc will not delete these commits since I still have tags that reference/have to commit is it tree?

Right -- since a tag still references that line of commits, they won't be disposed of.

> My second question, now that the I no longer have any tags/branch that reference/have in their history those commits, will git's gc completely delete those commit (at whatever interval it is set to)?

Yes, since there are no longer any references to them, they'll eventually be collected.